# Swift - sharing photos to Instagram

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

Im trying to implement `UIActivityViewController` to my app, It works correctly. However, I'd like to add *Instagram* to the options. When searching on the internet, I've seen this reply :

> "You're able to use UIActivityViewController to show up Instagram as
>   long there is just an UIImage inside the activity items. It won't show
>   up if you add more items like text, url etc. This is a bad limitation
>   made by Instagram.".

Is there any way, how to add *Instagram* even with initial text, or should I integrate another `UIActivityViewController` option and turn off all of the other options (FB, Twitter, mail) to show Instagram option? Maybe through if clauses for text?

Here ist the piece of code

```
@IBAction func ShareRecipe(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let initialText = "-Check out this app"
    let img: UIImage = ImageView.image!
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img, initialText], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I want to share image and text in Instagram. Did you get anything related this ?
Please help me.